# I need to select a column with distinct value from sql

Tags: sql

I am given a table which consists a column of various departments and another column consisting of various `dhdempno`. I need to select a unique `dhdempno` which represents the department head. A particular department has multiple employees with same `dhdmempno` and one unique `dhdempno` which represents the department head. What query shall i execute in order to obtain the result ?

Example

```
Department - dhdempno
abc           1  
abc           1 
abc           2  
asd           5  
asd           5
asd           6
```

The query should return

```
abc    2
asd    6
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind that result?  You need `select a unique dhdempno which represents the department head` or `The query should return abc - 2 , asd - 6`

Comment: why `asd - 6` why not `asd - 2` ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the query which will give result you are seeking.

```
select Department, dhdempno
from (
    SELECT Department, dhdempno, count(dhdempno) as counts
    FROM <your_table_name>
    group by Department, dhdempno ) as sub
where counts = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select departmentid, count(distinct dhdempno) as counting from your_table
group by departmentid
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Use Query like

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT,DHDEMPNO FROM DEPARTMENT
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT,DHDEMPNO
HAVING COUNT(DHDEMPNO)=1
```

will give you record with unique dhdempono in respective department

Comment: any comments for negative review will be appreciated. as its working good my side.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DepartmentId, MAX(dhdempno)
FROM [Table-name]
GROUP BY DepartmentId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select [Department],[dhdempno] from [dbo].[Your_Table_Name] where [dhdempno] in (select [dhdempno] from [dbo].[Your_Table_Name] group by [dhdempno] having count(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query:

```
select s.Department, max(s.dhdempno)as dhdempno from 
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENT, dhdempno FROM DUMMY
 ) s group by s.Department
```